# CS50 credit : how to change those if else conditions

Tags: c, cs50

I wanted to use those if else conditions to make the judgments, but it did not work. I suppose it is because `/` keeps the whole part. So I was wondering that: do I need to change this whole mechanism (if else conditions) or just is there anything in C I can use to replace `/`?

Thank you!

## American Express uses 15-digit numbers, starting with 34 or 37

```
if (answer / pow(10,13) == 34 | answer / pow(10,13) == 37 )
   {
       printf("AMEX\n");
   }
```

## MasterCard uses 16-digit numbers, starting with 51, 52, 53, 54, or 55

```
else if (answer / pow(10,14) == 51 | answer / pow(10,14) == 52 | answer / pow(10,14) == 53| answer / pow(10,14) == 54 )
   {
       printf("MASTERCARD\n");
   }
```

## Visa uses 13- and 16-digit numbers, starting with 4

```
else if (answer / pow(10,12) == 4 | (answer / pow(10,15) )== 4) 
   {
       printf("VISA\n");
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
double pow(double, double)
```

`pow` makes all the arithmetic switch from integers to double.

A simplest example illustrating your problem is:

```
1 / (double)10 == 0.01
```

is false, because of rounding errors. Never make `==` comparisons using floating point types.

I suggest you should move from double to integers, so to make your comparisons exact, ex:

```
unsigned long long answer = ...;
if (answer / 10000000000000ull == 34 | answer / 10000000000000ull == 37 )
... and so on ...
```

Or better, I suggest you move to strings, as i don't see a point in making arithmetic operations on a card number as a whole number. Or better, move to an array of digits.

```
const char answer[16];
scanf("%15s", answer);
if (strlen(answer) == 15 && answer[0] == '3' && (answer[1] == '4' || answer[1] == '7')) 
...
else if (strlen(asnwer) == 16 && answer[0] == '5' && ('1' <= answer[1] && answer[1] <= '4'))
 ... and so on
```